# How to Make my Android Application live On play Store

Tags: android

I have Made an Android application Which needs an Database to Store and retrieve the data. I Have made the Application Using the `SQLiteOpenHelper` . But as the application is working properly i want to host it to the Play store . 
Plz help me out what are the steps i have to go through.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-publish-an-Android-app-free-in-the-Google-Play-store

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create google developer account which worth 25$ for life time I guess.
And then you just need to follow their step by step. To export your .apk file, you need to generated signed apk with appropriate pro-guard rules.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en